# How I can remove hidden nan values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which has many nan values
when I am type the unique values :

```
plays.yardlineSide.unique()

array(['TB', 'DAL', nan, 'ATL', 'PHI', 'PIT', 'BUF', 'NYJ', 'CAR', 'MIN',
   'CIN', 'DET', 'SF', 'HOU', 'JAX', 'IND', 'SEA', 'TEN', 'ARI',
   'LAC', 'WAS', 'CLE', 'KC', 'MIA', 'NE', 'NO', 'GB', 'NYG', 'DEN',
   'CHI', 'LA', 'LV', 'BAL'], dtype=object)
```

but the dropna() isn't work instead it perform the rest of values by None like that :
ex : `plays.yardlineSide`
output : `0       None
1       None
2       None
3       None
4       None
...
8552    None
8553    None
8554    None
8555    None
8556    None

Comment: Please show how you're using `dropna()` - it's not clear what's being done here. Also see: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/13843268).

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work.

```
 import pandas as pd

 df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

 for col in df.columns:
     if df[col].isnull().sum() > 0:
         print("Column {} has {} hidden nan values".format(col, 
 df[col].isnull().sum()))
         df.drop(col, axis=1, inplace=True)

 df.to_csv("file_without_hidden_nan.csv", index=False)
```